# Cant find a spot to properly release MediaPlayer

Tags: android

i know there are tons of questions about `MediaPlayer` releasing, but i searched for hours and hours and everything contradicts each other.

Simple sitation: I create a `MediaPlayer` instance in `onCreate`. I have a play and a pause button. Where to release the `MediaPlayer`?
`onPause`/`onStop` causes a crash on resume, because `onCreate` wont always be called.
`onDestroy` seems not reliable because it wont always be called.

So where is the place to release a `MediaPlayer` that was create in `onCreate`?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private MediaPlayer sound;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);
    Log.d("Media", "onCreate: MediaPlayer created");

    Button buttonPlay = findViewById(R.id.button_play);
    buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sound.start();

        }
    });

    Button buttonPause = findViewById(R.id.button_pause);
    buttonPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sound.pause();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    sound.release();
    sound = null;
    Log.d("Media", "onDestroy: MediaPlayer released");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> onDestroy seems not reliable because it wont always be called

Either:

- `onDestroy()` will be called, or
- Your process was terminated, in which case the `MediaPlayer` goes away when your process does
- You had an unhandled exception, in which case you have bigger problems, or

> So where is the place to release a MediaPlayer that was create in onCreate?

`onDestroy()`.

Comment: Oh thanks god (and you), this topic was driving me crazy. Actually i had the same questions months ago and i just put it aside because i couldnt figure it out.

Comment: Please allow me to add one more little question, i dont want to open another topic: If i create a new instance of MediaPlayer in onCreate but with the same variable assigned to it, and dont release it in onDestroy, i would get an additional instance every time i rotate the device, right? And this would cause more and more memory consumption even if i dont play a sound?

Comment: @FlorianWalther: The default behavior of an `Activity` is for it to be destroyed and re-created on a configuration change, such as a screen rotation. So, you have one activity with one `MediaPlayer` before the rotation. After the rotation, you have a new activity with a new `MediaPlayer`, but the old activity will be destroyed, so your `onDestroy()` can release the previous `MediaPlayer`.

Comment: I mean if i dont release it in onDestroy. If i dont release it at all. Its just  a theoretical question to understand it better.

Comment: @FlorianWalther: The `MediaPlayer` instances should be garbage-collected after their activities are destroyed. It is possible that there is a problem specific to `MediaPlayer` that would cause a leak, but I do not know of one.

Comment: Yea i think there actually is one. Because the Android documentation specifically talks about multiple orientation changes without releaseing the resources to cause big memory problems. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html

I tried something like that by creating the MediaPlayer AND starting it immediatly in onCreate, without releasing it anywhere. When i rotate the device, it plays the sound file multiple times. +1 with every new orientation change.

Does that change anything about your answer or will a process termination 100% release the mediaplayer?

Comment: @FlorianWalther: "will a process termination 100% release the mediaplayer?" -- yes.

Comment: Thank you very much, you really saved me from a sleepless night.